# How to set up a rails form when asking for multiple check box items?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I want to ask my users, which of the following music styles they like:

- Jazz
- Classic
- ... etc.

Users can check at least one, or multiple music styles at the same time.

How should I set up this information in my database and rails? Should I use one database column (called "musicstyles" in this case) and enter data like this (does not properly work yet):

```
<%= f.check_box :musicstyles, {:multiple => true}, "classic", nil %> 
<%= f.check_box :musicstyles, {:multiple => true}, "jazz", nil  %>
<%= f.check_box :musicstyles, {:multiple => true}, "other", nil  %>
```

Or should I create one database column for each music style and ask for the information in a boolean manner?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that it doesn't matter which method you use, but the way that I would see to be the most clean would be to have a different column for each genre as a boolean. That way, you can check against each column very easily whenever you need to check what kind of music a certain user likes.